# Why Javascript function is sometimes defined inside comments block?

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding defining a javascript function.

Usually I see a javascript function is defined this way:

```
function test() {
  alert("test");
}
```

But I have seen people define a Javascript function inside comments block this way:

```
<!--
function test() {
  alert("test");
}
-->
```

Or sometimes people define a Javascript function inside comments block this way:

```
<!--
function test() {
  alert("test");
}
// -->
```

So what is the difference between the above 3 styles? In which case one style is preferable than other?

Thank You for reading this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It dates from the days when many browsers didn't support JavaScript, so didn't know what a `<script>` tag was.  By doing this:

```
<script>
<!--
function test() {
  alert("test");
}
// -->
</script>
```

Any browsers that didn't know what a `<script>` tag is would just see an HTML comment, and ignore it.

The second form, without the `//` on the final line, is actually invalid.  Whilst browsers that understand the `<script>` tag will ignore the opening HTML comment at the start of the block, that's all they will do, so without the JavaScript comment on the final line, they would attempt to parse `-->` as actual code.

The preferred form these days is just to use the first one, as every modern browser supports JavaScript.  Or, better still, put your code in a separate file if possible, and use `<script src="..."></script>` to keep your code separate from your views.

Comment: But the 2nd form still works even if it is invalid. How come?

Comment: A lot of people used to use that form without understanding the ramifications, I wouldn't be surprised if the latest browsers just ignore it.  In theory they should be displaying a syntax error